Как отследить какая кнопка нажата в выпадающем меню
Всем добрый день.
Подскажите как отследить какая кнопка нажата в впадающем меню.
           <div class="dropDownListConteiner"  onClick="dropDownListHandler(this)" show=0  id="status">
                <div class="dropDownListContent styleBorder" >
                    <div>
                       Статуc
                    </div>
                    <img src="download_file.html?file_id=746">
                </div>
                <div class="dropDownList styleBorder">
                    <div>
                        Назначена
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        В работе
                    </div> 
                    <div>
                        Отправлена на доработку
                    </div>  
                    <div>
                        Завершена
                    </div> 
                    <div>
                        Оценена
                    </div>  
                </div> 
            </div>

Я не ставил ни каких обработчиков на закрытие меню, оно само закрывается по клику на каком ни-будь элементе из выпадающего списка. Значит как я предполагаю, это событие как то возможно отследить. Google ни-чего не нашел.
    // Обработчик выпадающего меню.
    function dropDownListHandler(item) {
        var isShow = 0;
        isShow = $(item).attr('show');
        const currentPosition = $(item).offset().top + (($(item).height() * 1.3));

        // Вращение изображения.
        const triangle = $(item).find('img');

        // Позиционироване выпадающего меню.
        const containerList = $(item).children('div:last-child');
        containerList.offset({top: currentPosition});
        // Показываем/прячем меню.
        if (isShow == 0) {
            containerList.slideDown();
        } else {
            containerList.slideUp();
        }

        $(item).attr('show', isShow == 1 ? 0 : 1);
        triangle.css('transform', isShow == 0 ? 'rotate(-90deg)' : 'rotate(0deg)').css('transition', '0.5s');
       // $(item).children('div:first-child').children('div').text(isShow);
    };



Так вы добавьте обработчики на команды меню, и всё узнаете.

Ну понятно что если добавить на элементы (кнопки) обработчик
<div onClick="handlerDropDownItem()">
                        Назначена
</div>

Я то предполагал что есть из коробки метод обработки нажатия,

Так оно и работает, а не наоборот.

Ну у вас изначально это не готовый селект и даже не кнопки, а просто div-аки. Можно попробовать распознать, куда нажли через event.target.innerText какой нибудь

Лучше не innerText, а через data-аттрибуты

Я могу накидать варианты, как определить, по какому элементу нажали, однако только на чистом javaScript. Если можете менять разметку HTML, то лучше, как то промаркировать саму разметку - data-* атрибуты для этого хорошо подойду(как уже указали выше).
